# VBA Edit text XML text file, export to new file name

Tags: vba

used the site for years to assist me with VBA issues, I have a new issue today

I am trying to read an XML file and edit specific values in the file and then save as a new file in a new location
I cant import the XML file into excel due to the first line in the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
```

this is what I believe anyway - maybe wrong I get this error

"XML document must have a top level element" error

I have over 60 files and don't want to edit any parts in case it causes a problem with the import - the files are not used in excel they are used in the NICE Quality tool, but I have to change the same value in all to get them to input into the new system

```
Public Sub RemoveLines()

Dim inFilePath As String
Dim outFilePath As String
Dim inFile As Integer
Dim outFile As Integer
Dim lineCount As Long
Dim fileLine As String
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""'
    r = ActiveCell.Value
    rs = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    rt = Left(r, Len(r) - 4)
    rst = Left(rs, Len(rs) - 4)
    inFilePath = "H:\Desktop\Nimas Exports\" & r
    inFilePathtemp = "H:\Desktop\Nimas Exports\temp" & r
    outFilePath = "H:\Desktop\Engage Imports\" & rs
    If Dir$(inFilePath) = "" Then Exit Sub
        
        inFile = FreeFile
        Open inFilePath For Input As #inFile
        outFile = FreeFile
        Open outFilePath For Output As #outFile
        lineCount = 0
        Do Until EOF(inFile)
            Line Input #inFile, fileLine
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
            fileLine = Replace(fileLine, "<nvcFormName>" & rt & "</nvcFormName>", "<nvcFormName>" & rst & "</nvcFormName>")
            fileLine = Replace(fileLine, " <nvcVersion>4.1.5</nvcVersion>", " <nvcVersion>6.3.5</nvcVersion>")
            Print #outFile, fileLine
        Loop
        
        Close #inFile
        Close #outFile
   Kill inFilePathtemp
   Name outFilePath As inFilePath
Loop

End Sub
```

Code above is what I am using but it seems to get to "do until EOF" and then closes the file without doing the replace

here is the first few lines of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<BaseEvaluationFormData xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/BaseEvaluationFormData.xsd">
  <tblForm>
    <iFormID>-1</iFormID>
    <tiFormType>1</tiFormType>
    <nvcFormName>rob test new</nvcFormName>
    <ntBluePrint>&lt;Form type ="NiceApplications.EvaluationForms.Client.Shared.FormComponents.QUCEvaluationForm" name="rob test new" &gt;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add a sample xml file? I am not sure if your issue is because of first line (as you mentioned). The error is saying that you don't have a root element and hence your xml is not valid. Do you want to add a root in all your files? Also, editing xml file as a text file is not advisable.

Comment: the XML files are large and contain client info - so not sure that I would be allowed to show the file , I can edit the files fine in notepad and then save them manually and upload to new system and all is ok  so thought I could do same with VBA

Comment: You can do the same with VBA. But you need to provide a [mcve], because there is no way to *guess* what is wrong with your files. "I've posted the first six lines" will not cut it, as this is not valid XML. Cut down on the XML, yes, but it should still contain the nodes you want to change and produce the error you see, with the code sample you provide.